# Calling PFXExportCertStoreEx in Go does not return data

Tags: go, system-calls, x509, certificate-store

I'm working in Go 1.6 on Windows and trying to export a certificate container to a PFX (the ultimate goal here is to access an exportable private key from the certificate store).

I have opened a memory store and inserted a certificate into the store:

```
var storedCertCtx *syscall.CertContext
storeHandle, err := syscall.CertOpenStore(syscall.CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY, 0, 0, syscall.CERT_STORE_DEFER_CLOSE_UNTIL_LAST_FREE_FLAG, 0)
err = syscall.CertAddCertificateContextToStore(storeHandle, certenum, syscall.CERT_STORE_ADD_ALWAYS, &storedCertCtx)
```

Now I want to generate a PFX of that store. I have defined a struct for containing the [data blob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381414(v=vs.85).aspx) and want to use [PFXExportCertStoreEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387313(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a PFX of the store:

```
var (
    crypt32                  = syscall.NewLazyDLL("crypt32.dll")
    procPFXExportCertStoreEx = crypt32.NewProc("PFXExportCertStoreEx")
)

type CRYPTOAPI_BLOB struct {
    DataSize uint32
    Data     *byte
}

var pfxBlob CRYPTOAPI_BLOB
err = PfxExportCertStore(storeHandle, &pfxBlob, syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("MyPassword"), 0, 0)

syscall.Syscall6(procPFXExportCertStoreEx.Addr(), 5,
        uintptr(storeHandle),                //hStore
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pfxBlob)),   //*pPFX
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("password"))), //szPassword
        0,   //*pvPara
        0,   //dwFlags
        0)
```

And this *half* works.

`DataSize` is populated with what looks like an appropriate value (i.e. if I add more certificates to the store, it grows bigger), however `Data` is *always* `<nil>`.

Seeing as it's meant to be populated with a pointer, I have tried declaring it as `*uintptr` and `uint32` (just to see if *anything* gets populated), but nothing. The value is always untouched (if I manually put junk data in there, the junk data stays after the syscall is executed).

Have I defined the struct incorrectly? There is precious few examples to go for getting this done in Go, but from what I can see from the numerous C examples, this *should* be working.

Comment: By "blank", do you mean `pfxBlob.Data == 0`, or do you mean the block of memory where `Data` points is empty?

Comment: @JimB if I do a `fmt.Println(pfxBlob.Data)` I get `<nil>`. I also just noticed that the struct I pasted into the code snippet was from a previous revision, which I will just update to what I've got as the latest.

Comment: Have you tried checking the return value and the error after the call?

Comment: From a quick google, it looks like this is the expected behavior: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387313(v=vs.85).aspx -- from reading that it looks like you need to pre-allocate the buffer and put the size in `cbData`. If `pbData` is nil, the call only returns the size needed.

Comment: @JimB GetLastError() returns nothing, and the syscall's first return indicates success.

Comment: @JimB I think you are correct. I have read that page so many times but the importance of that sentence never sank in. If I initialise `pfx` blob with `pfxBlob := CRYPTOAPI_BLOB{Data: new(byte)}` I seem to be getting the appropriate pointer now. If you'd like to post that as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: @JimB, your response should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

According to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387313(v=vs.85).aspx, the `pPFX` struct requires a pre-allocated buffer, with the size in the `cbData` field, which will be updated with the size of the data copied in.

If the call is made with `pbData` equal to `NULL`, only the `cbData` field is updated to reflect the size needed for the output buffer.

Comment: The issue I have is on first run it reports a size of 3075, then when I Initialize the buffer, it only writes 3065 bytes and my certificate won't instantiate when the raw byte data is used with the C# X509Certificate2 constructor that accepts a byte[]...

Answer (score 0):

JimB's answer is most certainly correct, but I want to add this for followup in case anyone else is going down this path. The actual code that I had to use to get the PFX file into `CRYPTOAPI_BLOB` was:

```
var (
    crypt32                  = syscall.NewLazyDLL("crypt32.dll")
    procPFXExportCertStoreEx = crypt32.NewProc("PFXExportCertStoreEx")
    procCryptMemAlloc        = crypt32.NewProc("CryptMemAlloc")
    procCryptMemFree         = crypt32.NewProc("CryptMemFree")
)

type CRYPTOAPI_BLOB struct {
    cbData uint32
    pbData *byte
}

func (b *CRYPTOAPI_BLOB) ToByteArray() []byte {
    d := make([]byte, b.cbData)
    copy(d, (*[1 << 30]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(b.pbData))[:])
    return d
}

func PfxExportCertStore(storeHandle syscall.Handle, password string, flags uint32) (returnData []byte, err error) {

    var pfxBlob CRYPTOAPI_BLOB

    r1, _, _ := syscall.Syscall6(procPFXExportCertStoreEx.Addr(), 5,
        uintptr(storeHandle),                                        //hStore
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pfxBlob)),                           //*pPFX
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(password))), //szPassword
        0,              //*pvPara
        uintptr(flags), //dwFlags
        0)

    r2, _, _ := syscall.Syscall(procCryptMemAlloc.Addr(), 1, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pfxBlob.cbData)), 0, 0)

    p := unsafe.Pointer(&r2)
    q := (*byte)(p)
    pfxBlob.pbData = q
    defer syscall.Syscall(procCryptMemFree.Addr(), 1, uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pfxBlob.pbData)), 0, 0)

    r3, _, _ := syscall.Syscall6(procPFXExportCertStoreEx.Addr(), 5,
        uintptr(storeHandle),                                        //hStore
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&pfxBlob)),                           //*pPFX
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(password))), //szPassword
        0,              //*pvPara
        uintptr(flags), //dwFlags
        0)


    returnData = pfxBlob.ToByteArray()
    return
}
```

(I have stripped the error handling to make it easier to read). The first call to `PFXExportCertStoreEx` just returns the size, and once we have the size we can do a call to `PFXExportCertStoreEx` to allocate a buffer, and then we pass the same pointer to `PFXExportCertStoreEx`, but this time it has the allocated buffer, and we get the full PFX file returned.

Comment: Maybe you can help with the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004401/use-in-memory-certificate-for-client-authentication ? Had to go and get 50 points just to ask this :)