# Use in memory certificate for client authentication

Tags: winapi, go, https, system-calls, x509

I have a non-exportable certificate in my windows box which works fine with IE and Chrome when I try to access websites.

I would like to be able to use this certificate from a Go CLI application to access a HTTPS URI that requires client certificate authentication but also a non standard CA cert which I suppose I need to add to the request if its not already there.

Some code example would be appreciated since documentation I found concerning calls do not have any.

I suppose that I would use [PFXExportCertStoreEx API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387313(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to extract the certificate from memory.

I also found this which might help [Calling PFXExportCertStoreEx in Go does not return data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634088/calling-pfxexportcertstoreex-in-go-does-not-return-data/35635176) but it doesn't show how to use the certificate in a https call.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. It seems you found an answer to "how to extract certificate". It may or may not need to be converted before setting the certificate in the [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config). You should be able to find many examples showing [how to use client certificates](http://www.bite-code.com/2015/06/25/tls-mutual-auth-in-golang/).

Comment: At the moment I am trying to see how to get the data from the store. The tls.Config part shouldn't be that hard and there are a lot of examples as long as you get the certificate in the correct format.

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned in the answer to "Calling PFXExportCertStoreEx in Go..."? It seems like the OP put an answer with working code, though I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Yes, I'm working based on that. I get a []byte of length 85 but dunno what to do with that :)

Comment: It looks like PFX is an older version of [PKCS#12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12). A quick google finds [this package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/pkcs12) for Go. Honestly, I would just save the raw bytes and try to figure out exactly what's in it using openssl, then port this to actual code.

Comment: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376559(v=vs.85).aspx) shows that you can export in X509_ASN_ENCODING when you open the store which is required to be passed to the PfxExportCertStore. Not sure I need the lib you mentioned but its worth the try.

Comment: @Marc I tried and the example [goplay](https://play.golang.org/p/p1JrowBN3c6) returns something but I get a message that the password is wrong.